# Using passed Variable as Key/Value pair in Mixins

Tags: sass, mixins

I tried looking this up, but have not had success. I could not be looking with the right search parameters.

I'm creating a mixin in SASS the will allow me to create keyframes by passing the animation name, from value and to value. Here's an example:

```
@mixin keyframes($name, $from, $to) {
    @-webkit-keyframes #{$name} {
        from {
            left: $from
        }
        to {
            left: $to
        }
    }
}
```

This is a shorter version as I would also add lines for @-moz-keyframes and @keyframes. I prefer this method so that I'm not having to repeat "from" and "to" in the animations and having the mixin just grab it using @content, but I also don't want to assume that "left" is the only property that is going to be affected.

What I'd like to do is treat both $from and $to variables as Objects so that they can contain a series of key/value pairs. When  I attempt this:

```
$mixin keyframes($name, $from, $to) {
    @-webkit-keyframes #{$name} {
        from {
            $from
        }
        to {
            $to
        }
    }
}
```

...I get compile errors because it's excepting a key/value pair and not a variable.

Is there a way to tell SASS to treat $from and $to as a series of key/value pairs? I tried #{$from} already and it still throws that compile error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that because property/values aren't strings.  You would have to write it using mappings, like this:

```
@mixin keyframes($name, $from, $to) {
    @-webkit-keyframes #{$name} {
        from {
            @each $prop, $val in $from {
              #{$prop}: $val;
            }
        }
        to {
            @each $prop, $val in $to {
              #{$prop}: $val;
            }
        }
    }
}

@include keyframes(foo, (top: 10px), (top: 50px));
```

However, I would recommend not doing this at all if your goal is to write a flexible mixin.  Just write out your own from/to statements:

```
@mixin keyframes($name) {
    @-webkit-keyframes #{$name} {
        @content
    }
}

@include keyframes(foo) {
  from {
    top: 10px;
  }

  to {
    top: 50px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Cimmanon! Even if I don't go this route at the end, it will be nice at least knowing how to do this. :)